# Configure Zxing to read only QR Code in Xamarin for faster response

Tags: performance, xamarin, response, zxing, configure

Is it possible to configure Zxing reader to read only QR Code,  programmatically? (When clicking the start scan button for example)? If yes, then how can I do that?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#barcode-formats)

```
var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() { 
    ZXing.ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
};

var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(); 
var result = await scanner.Scan(options);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much Jason!